# Data tables server-side formating links

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables

I have a table with tones of records and I need some links inside the table, so the problem is about formatting...

The first row is a link of the name of the patient to his single page and the last row is a collection of links for edit and delete the patient.

**The problem:**

1. Now with this code in the first row don't appear the name (row[1]),
   appear the surnames (row[2]) but the link is ok (row[0])
2. In the last row both links are working good, but thickybox is not
   working, the link is opened in a new page.

Can somebody help me with that? thank's in advance!!! :)

**Server-side processing script:**

```
$columns = array(
    array( 
            'db' => 'id', 
            'dt' => 0,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                $links='<a href="paciente/'.$row[0].'/0/">'.$row[1].'</a>';
                return $links;
        }),
    array( 'db' => 'apellidos',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'tel_mov',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'terapeuta',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 
            'db' => 'id', 
            'dt' => 4,
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                $links2='<a href="print-historia.php?height=655&amp;width=800&amp;id='.$row[0].'&amp;pacientes=si" class=" thickbox editar txt_petit"><img src="ima/edit.png" /></a> | <a href="?borrar=total&amp;id='.$row[0].'" onClick="return confirmSubmit()" class="borrar txt_petit"><img src="ima/close.png" /></a>';
                return $links2;
        }),

);
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tablet').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"},
        "scrollY":        "400px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "load.php"
        });
    } );
```

Comment: Why not try returning all the data and using a `render` function on the `columns` array? That way you'll not need to worry about the query in PHP.

Comment: I don't know how thickbox works, but I imagine the problem is related to the way you're binding thickbox to the click event

Answer (score 0):

I got it ;)

**For the links names problems**:

Just add first column of the table a *id* data and if you don't need it hide it with options in the javascript ("bVisible": false)

So now the $row[0] is always the id and the $row[1] the name...

**For the thickbox problem:**

Just add *"aoColumns"* whith the options an after *"fnDrawCallback"*

```
    "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "id","bVisible": false},
            { "sTitle": "Nombre" },
            { "sTitle": "Apellidos" },
            { "sTitle": "Móbil","bSortable": false },
            { "sTitle": "Fijo","bSortable": false },
            { "sTitle": "Terapeuta","bSortable": false },
            { "sTitle": "Edición","bSortable": false,"bSearchable": false }],
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            tb_init('a.thickbox');

          }
```

I don't know if is the best way but is working for me ;)